# Discord .Net Read messages as a user (not a bot)

Tags: c#, .net, discord, discord.net

I am currently using a discord .Net api to handle a bot and all events related to its associated server. However, I need to perform also some actions as my personal user, not a bot.

In telegram there is a different api for that, for bot and for a user. How should it be done with discord? Could you please provide an example in .net for the authorization?

Comment: User-bots are against Discord's TOS and is undoable via Discord API

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to login with your own token and not a bot token you will not be able to use discord.net. you'll have to use the nuget package called AnarchyWrapper (not suggested, can cause a discord ban)